# spring aop for only for specific methods

Tags: java, spring-aop

we need to implement spring aop in our project. Is there any way in the spring configuration that we need to apply aop only for
some specific methods ? 
for example: I need to initialize some variables through spring aop only to the method which starts with 'create'. eg:createEmployee(Employee employee);
Is it possible to implement without using aspectJ in spring?
Is it clear? or should I explain more? How do I do that? can I apply some kind of filter to the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible, this way

```
<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="hibernateTxManager">
        <tx:attributes>        
            <tx:method name="create*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />            
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```